# É possivel criar um arquivo JS para todas as páginas?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho várias páginas, gostaria de saber se é possível usar o mesmo *JS* para a mesma pagina.

Por exemplo:

> Tenho uma página HOME, onde eu carrego as paginas "filho" dentro de uma `div` (content), mas para cada página, eu preciso criar um novo arquivo *JS*.

```
$("#lista_cli").click(function(){
    $('#content').css('display', 'none');
    $("#content").load('lista_clientes.php');
    $("#content").fadeIn(2000);
});

$("#cadastro_cli").click(function(){
    $('#content').css('display', 'none');
    $("#content").load('cadastra_cliente.php');
    $("#content").fadeIn(2000); 
});
```

Andei fazendo alguns testes, em algum momento, quando eu dou um `ALERT` no arquivo *JS* da página home, em um conteúdo da outra página (depois de carregada), ele me exibe um `alert` corretamente, porem as requisições *AJAX* não funcionam. Talvez tenha ficado meio confunso, mas basicamente:

**É possível utilizar o mesmo *JS* em varias páginas? é recomendado?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o código no arquivo JS for comum à mais de uma página, com certeza você pode reutilizá-lo, não só pode como deve, afinal essa é uma das principais vantagens de separar o código javascript em um arquivo separado do html.

Para utilizar o mesmo arquivo em mais de uma página, basta importá-lo em suas páginas html, ex.:

```
<script src="meuScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Só pra complementar, o reúso de códigos é uma boa prática, como o Arnaldo já disse, não só por evitar duplicação desnecessária de código, mas por facilitar a manutenção. Imagine que você tem um alert genérico que você usa-o em todas as telas e você precisa alterar todos os textos desse alert. Ao invés de ficar indo página por página arrumar cada código de alert, você, tendo compartilhado (reusado) ele em outras páginas, consegue alterar o código apenas 1x e tendo um efeito "global".